# Set Access expire for a Folder Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've created a script to create folders on Google Drive and set access rightds to different users abased on a list from a Google Sheet using a script.  Is there a way to set the Access Expiry for each folder by a script using a value from the sheet?  I looked through the documentation but I could not find a solution.

Thank

Comment: access on google drive is until you remove it.  There is no default way to expire access.

Comment: @DaImTo Permission Expiration is a relatively new feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the permission expiration using the Advanced Drive service.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource

It would look like:

```
  var permission = Drive.newPermission();
  permission.expirationDate = new Date(2016,11,25).toISOString();
  permission.type = "user"
  permission.value = "person@myDomain.org"
  permission.role = "reader"
  Drive.Permissions.insert(permission, fileId)
```